# How can I compute this limit

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to prove that

$\lim_{h\rightarrow\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\cos ht-1\right)\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]dt\right)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]dt$

where 
$\underset{t}{\triangle}\eta(t)=\eta(t)+\eta(-t)$ and $\phi$ is an integrable function (in the lebesgue sense), to be precise it is the fourier transform of an integrable density function and thus continuous. Also $\phi$ is differentiable at $0$.

According to the authors of this [paper](http://ora.ouls.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid%3Aa4c3ad11-74fe-458c-8d58-6f74511a476c/datastreams/ATTACHMENT01) (see proof of theorem 3), this can be achieved by showing $\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]$ is integrable and the result will follow from the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

They do this by showing that $\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]$ is uniformly bounded. And this is the part of the proof I am stuck on. Can anyone show me how to prove $\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]$ is uniformly bounded and integrable?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the Riemann Lebesgue lemma?

Comment: If $\phi(t)/t$ is integrable, then the result would seem to follow from the Riemann--Lebesgue lemma. As it's stated, I think it might be false. Consider $\phi(t) = i e^{i t x} \chi_{[0,1]}(t)$ where $\chi_{A}(t)$ is the (set) characteristic function. Then $\int_0^1 |\cos(ht)/t| = \infty$ for each $h$ and so the integrand is not Lebesgue integrable. Have I screwed something up? (Likely.)

Comment: I agree with cardinal, you probably need to give more information about $\phi$.

Comment: @cardinal , @Willie, @Prometheus ... The only extra information i have on $\phi$ is that it is the fourier transform of an integrable density function and hence continuous. I think what needs to be shown is that $\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}$ is lebesgue integrable and then the result would follow from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. But I couldn't show this is an integrable function. Any ideas? Incidentally the above result is required to prove theorem 3 of the following [paper](http://ora.ouls.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid%3Aa4c3ad11-74fe-458c-8d58-6f74511a476c/datastreams/ATTACHMENT01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding the question, but here's what I think (I apologize ahead of time as it is late!)

Write $\eta(t) = \displaystyle\mathop{\Delta}_{t} \left[\frac{\phi(t) e^{-itx}}{it} \right] = \frac{\phi(t) e^{-itx} - \phi(-t) e^{itx}}{it}$.

Then,

$$
\begin{array}
\\
\int_0^{\infty} (cos(ht) - 1) \eta(t) dt & = \left.\left( \frac{1}{h} \sin(ht) - t\right) \eta(t)\right|_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{\sin(ht)}{ht}\right)t \eta'(t) dt \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{\sin(ht)}{ht} \right) t \eta'(t) dt
\end{array}
$$
 by parts (which is justified as the author assumes $\phi$ is differentiable at the origin).  The Dominated Convergence Theorem implies that
$$
\lim_{h \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{\sin(ht)}{ht} \right) t \eta'(t) dt = \int_0^{\infty} t \eta'(t) dt.
$$
Again, by parts, we have
$$
\int_0^{\infty} t \eta'(t) dt = \left. t \eta(t)\right|_0^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} \eta(t) dt = - \int_0^{\infty} \eta(t) dt.
$$

Putting it altogether gives:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \left( \cos(ht) - 1\right) \eta(t) dt = - \int_0^{\infty} \eta(t) dt.
$$

Comment: impressive! ... This is the trail of thought I was following. If $\eta(t)$ is lebesgue integrable. Then by the Riemann lebesgue lemma the fourier transform $\widehat{\eta}(h) \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow \infty$, in particular $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(ht)\eta(t)dt \rightarrow 0$. But the crux is trying to show $\eta(t)$ is lebesgue integrable. If this could be done it would certainly make the proof shorter. I've almost given up at this stage. But if you see this please let me know.

Comment: Infact I'm sure now there is a shorter method. See my edits to the question above.

Comment: It was merely a "follow the logic train" exercise.  I have no doubt that it can be improved, if it is even correct (I did not justify each step rigorously).  I think the crux of the matter is actually showing that $\eta(t)$ is Lebesgue integrable at $0$, as the exponential seems to demand convergence at $0$.  Be careful, however, about splitting up the integral into $\int \left( \cos(ht) - 1 \right) \eta(t) dt = \int\cos(ht) \eta(t) - \int \eta(t)$, as Didier points out that each integral need not converge separately.

Comment: why though? if $\eta(t)$ is integrable, as the proof of the theorem claims (which I think I now know why) then both the integrals on the right hand side should be finite.

Answer (score 4):

The proof of Theorem 3 is discussing $\int_0^\infty exp(-itx) \phi(t) \frac{\cos(ht)-1}{t}\, dt$.  That -1 makes a big difference.

Comment: @Robert Israel, I dont agree, the integral the author claims to tend to $0$ as $h \rightarrow \infty$ (i.e. the $\cos ht$ part of the integrand, see line after equation A.2) is precisely, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(ht\right)\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)+\phi\left(-t\right)\exp\left(itx\right)}{it}dt$,  which equals $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(ht\right)\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos\left(ht\right)\frac{\phi\left(-t\right)\exp\left(itx\right)}{it}dt$. The first term is the one I asked about.

Comment: @aukie That's funny: (A.2) does discuss the integral @Robert says, with the $(\cos(ht)-1)$ term (and certainly not $\cos(ht)$ alone, for good reasons), but you *don't agree*... Oh well.

Comment: @Didier, @Robert, hmmm, seems like im being silly. Equation A.2 reads $\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}(\cos ht-1)\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]dt$. Which can be expanded as $\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos ht\underset{t}{\triangle}\left[\frac{\phi(t)\exp\left(-itx\right)}{it}\right]dt-\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\underset{t}{\triangle}[\frac{\phi(t)\exp(-itx)}{it}]dt$. From my understanding the author claims the first term in this sum goes to zero (which i wonder how?). And the second term goes to $2F(x)-1$. Are you saying this is not right??

Comment: @aukie *Which can be expanded*... but should not be, in any circumstances, under a penalty of divergent-at-zero integrals.